# Get and work at the line of java exception

Tags: java, exception

Say we have 6 lines of code written in Java and x exception can occur any time at any line out of 6.

How I can catch only that line of code and work on that in a catch block.
If an exception occurs at the 2nd line it shall get that line and work on that.

Please let me know if this is possible in Java.

Thanks,

Comment: wrap each of the 6 lines in a *separate* try/catch? But is this *really* the case? And, of course, *it shall get that line* - makes perfect sense

Comment: You can breakpoint on a specific exception being thrown. That way you can see what happens on this Exception no matter where it happens in the code.

Comment: Read the stack trace?

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to check the exception where it occurs. I need a code which catches that exception causing line and again works on that automatically. The point is, say 6 lines are in  try block and out of 6 lines you get exception at 2nd for this to handle I need different code, if 3rd I need different code. So I want to trigger different code for each line if exception occurs at any of them.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
x.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber();
```

along with a switch case block

Comment: Thanks, could you please give me an example of code. What I understood I shall get the line number and somehow be using switch case I should write the code to execute the same line again.

Answer (score 0):

Note that using exceptions to control the flow of your program is usually not the best approach. But if you really want to do it, then maybe this could work?

```
int stepCompleted = 0;

try {
    doFirst();
    ++stepCompleted;
    doSecond();
    ++stepCompleted;
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {

    switch(stepCompleted) {

        case 0:
            // Do stuff ...
            break;

        case 1:
            // Do stuff ...
            break;
        ...
}
```